# Convert a one line vector (array) assignation to classical array, C++ translation to C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, vector, c99

I'm trying to convert the Moller Trumbore algorithm, as seen [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-to-assign-calculate-triangle-texture-coordinates).

The goal of this code is to search the intersection point of a vector with a triangle, and it also return the U and V texture point.

But, I 'm stuck with this line:

`Vector uvHit = uvVectors[0] * u + uvVectors[1] * v + uvVectors[2] * (1 - u - v);`

Who can also be seen as:

`*uvHit = u * uvVectors[0] + v * uvVectors[1] + (1 - u - v) * uvVectors[2];`

here is my code:

```
typedef float vec_t;
typedef vec_t vec3_t[3];

qboolean GetIntersection(vec3_t rayOrigin, vec3_t rayDirection, float hitDistance, vec3_t *uv)
{
vec3_t pvec;
float det = 0.0f;
vec3_t tvec;
vec3_t qvec;
vec3_t uvHit;

// begin calculating determinant - also used to calculate U parameter
CrossProduct(rayDirection, edge2, pvec);

// if determinant is near zero, ray lies in plane of triangle
det = DotProduct(edge1, pvec);

const float EPSILON = 0.000001f;

if ((det > -EPSILON) && (det < EPSILON))
    return qfalse;

float inv_det = 1.0f / det;

// calculate distance from vertex 0 to ray origin
tvec = rayOrigin - verts[0];

// calculate U parameter and test bounds
u = DotProduct(tvec, pvec) * inv_det;


if ((u < 0.0f) || (u > 1.0f))
    return false;

// prepare to test V parameter
CrossProduct(tvec, edge1, qvec);

// calculate V parameter and test bounds
float v = DotProduct(rayDirection, qvec) * inv_det;

if ((v < 0.0f) || (u + v > 1.0f))
    return false;

Vector uvHit = uvVectors[0] * u + uvVectors[1] * v + uvVectors[2] * (1 - u - v);// This is the line I don't understand 

uv[0] = uvHit[0];
uv[1] = uvHit[1];
uv[2] = 0;

// calculate t, ray intersects triangle
hitDistance = DotProduct(edge2, qvec) * inv_det;

// only allow intersections in the forward ray direction
return hitDistance >= 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's matrix multiplication? It looks like ordinary arithmetic.

Comment: You need to show how the `Vector` type is defined, and the declarations of all the variables.

Comment: Nothing here looks like a C++ `std::vector`.

Comment: That `Vector` class isn't related at all to C++ `std::vector`. It represents vector graphics.

Comment: OK, my bad. But how to convert it anyway please?

Comment: You need to find the library that they're using to see how it's defined so you can figure out how to translate it. It's not anything standard.

Comment: Please forget the vector, imagine something like: *uvHit = u * uvVectors[0] + v * uvVectors[1] + (1 - u - v) * uvVectors[2];

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. That's just ordinary C code.

Comment: As you are stuck with the title, I change it.

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. `*uvHit = u * uvVectors[0] + v * uvVectors[1] + (1 - u - v) * uvVectors[2]` is setting a single value. So we can't understand how you think it can be equivalent to setting multiple values in an array.

Comment: Without knowing what `Vector` really is, there is a lot of guessing. And BTW: unless that is a scalar data type(which I don't assume) it must be C++.

Comment: I know, I had to edit and remove the C ++ part of my question so that people stop downvoting my question.

Comment: @GUNNM Since your question is about translating a piece of C++ code to C, using both tags is appropriate. However, from the question itself it wasn't at all clear that that's what you wanted to do. I'm sure you wouldn't have been downvoted like that if you had provided more context, so that people could better understand your question.

Comment: Felix, I change question, tag, and add my code.

Comment: @GUNNM That's much better. However, we still don't know how `Vector` is defined in the original C++ source code, which is very important since it's probably a class with overloaded operators. Therefore `+` and `*` could mean pretty much anything, and we can't know how they work without the definition of `Vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating a point in a triangle from its vertices represented as `Vector uvVectors[3]` and its barycentric coordinates `u`, `v` and `w == 1 - u - v`.

In the C++ code you've shown, `Vector` is probably a class or a struct. The multiplication operator `*` has been overloaded, in this case to the multiplication of a vector with a scalar:

```
Vector uvHit = uvVectors[0] * u + uvVectors[1] * v + uvVectors[2] * (1 - u - v);
```

In C, you can't overload operators, so you have to write this calculation explicitly. Let's assume that your vector is a vector in 3D space:

```
typedef struct Vector Vector;

struct Vector {
    double x, y, z;
};
```

Then your multiplication looks like this when you initialize a vector:

```
Vector uvHit = {
    uvVectors[0].x * u + uvVectors[1].x * v + uvVectors[2].x * (1 - u - v),
    uvVectors[0].y * u + uvVectors[1].y * v + uvVectors[2].y * (1 - u - v),
    uvVectors[0].z * u + uvVectors[1].z * v + uvVectors[2].z * (1 - u - v)
};
```

or like this when you assign its values later:

```
uvHit.x = uvVectors[0].x * u + uvVectors[1].x * v + uvVectors[2].x * (1 - u - v);
uvHit.y = uvVectors[0].y * u + uvVectors[1].y * v + uvVectors[2].y * (1 - u - v);
uvHit.z = uvVectors[0].z * u + uvVectors[1].z * v + uvVectors[2].z * (1 - u - v);
```

Comment: I don't get the uvVectors[0].x as it's not an array nor a pointer?

Comment: But the `uvVectors[0]` is right there in your origibnal C++ code, so it must have been an array of vectors, no? My guess is that this array of vectors is an array of the three location vectors of a triangle's vertices. Yes, I'm guessing here, because you don't give enough information in your post.

Comment: (In the code at the link you posted, the definition of `uvVector` is not shown. The function there is probably a method of a class, where `uvVector` is defined.)

Comment: Another implementation here: https://www.scratchapixel.com/code.php?id=9&origin=/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle  the "Interpolate colors using the barycentric coordinates" part, even if in this one, it's refer to a color array, the implementation logic is the same.

Comment: In your answer, x, y and z have the same value.

Comment: I've answered your question, which really was how to implement the multiplication of a vector with a scalar that was a single operaton in C++ in C. I'm not really interested in the texture stuff you're trying to do. I have the impression that you could benefit from understanding the algorithm at a more abstract level, not by looking at concrete implementations. If you are looking at concrete implementations, you must look at all of it, not just at some excerpts, and you must understand how the data is represented.

Comment: No. The code I've shown is a definition with an initialization. The first line initializes `uvHit.x`, the second line `uvHit.y` and the third line `uvHit.z`. They don't have the same value.

Comment: What is uvVectors[0].x ? Sorry but your answer cannot work.

Comment: The code works -- [look here](https://ideone.com/NeJBDX) --, but as I've said, your question isn't very clear and I've had to make assumptions. That's the whole problem here: You don't understand the original C++ or C# code and want to port it to C nonetheless.

Comment: @GUNNM It's not a 3x3 matrix, it's an array of 3 points which together define a triangle.

Comment: In the code that you finally posted, `uvHit` is the point where your ray intersects the triangle. It is calculated exactly in the way I describe above. Even after adding your post, we don't know what your `vec_t` looks like. Is it an array of three doubles? Your code seems to use `uv[0]`, `uv[1]` and `uv[2]`, where I have used `uv.x`, `uv.y` and `uv.z`.

Comment: OK, I was wrong, it's not a vec3. But an array of 3 vec3. My apologies M Oehm.

Comment: Yes, vec_t is an array of 3 float.

Comment: I assumed "uvVectors" was a typo for "uv". In fact, I was wrong, but the original code was incomplete. uvVectors comes out of nowhere.